# jQuery append(), prepend(), html() equivalent in angular 2

Tags: jquery, typescript, angular, ecmascript-6

I'm creating an element as follows:

```
let tmplt=``;
      for(let i=0;i<wht.length;i++){
        tmplt +=`<li title="${wht[i]}" style="color:#000">
          <span (click)="slctRmv($event)">×</span>${wht[i]}
          </li>`;
      }
      jQuery("#myId").prepend(tmplt);
```

It is appending to the myId but click event is not triggering as in template.

So is there solution for this in angular2.

Comment: what is this `let` syntax?

Comment: @madalinivascu ES6 syntax

Answer (score 2):

Direct DOM manipulation should be avoided in Angular2.

You can get a reference to an anchor element like

```
@Component({
  selector: '...',
  template: `<div><span #myAnchor></span></div>`})
class MyComponent {
  @ViewChildren('myAnchor') myAnchor;

  constuctor(private renderer:Renderer) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // this.myAnchor.nativeElement.appendChild();
    this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.myAnchor, 'appendChild', []);
  }
}
```

or other methods HTML elements provide see [Node.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

But prefer the methods [Renderer](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Renderer-class.html) provides.

You can also use

```
<div><span [innerHTML]="someField"></div>
```

with

```
class MyComponent {
  someField:string = '<div>xxx</div>';
}
```

Comment: #myId is dynamically created so there is no #myId in my view initially

Comment: `(click)="slctRmv($event)"` or any other kind of Angular binding syntax doesn't work in dynamically added HTML. Components or directives are not instantiated neither. You probably want [DynamicComponentLoader](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html)

Comment: yes, I also suspect so, but how to use it in my scenario?

Comment: What is your scenario? This might work for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468

Answer (score 0):

You can include the likes of jquery, although it's not advised if your intention is to modify stuff in the view.

You could also build a lite version https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-lite.

a genuine use case might be an external library returning some html , and you need to internally do some DOM manipulation on the returned html and send it to another service. It can be quite time consuming writing vanilla JS for that.